# How to remove the first and last letter of a string?

Tags: python, string

I'd like to remove the first and last letter from a string. So far I've made something like this:

```
string = "wildcatatewonderfulcake"
first_letter_remvoer = string.strip(string[0])
print(first_letter_remvoer)
second_letter_remover = first_letter_remvoer.strip(string[-1])
print(second_letter_remover)
```

But sadly if the first letter is for example `'c'` and `'c'` exists more then once in a given string, it deletes every single `'c'` from the string. Same goes with the last letter.

Comment: What is your desired result for this example?

Comment: Finall output = "ildcatatewonderfulcak"

Comment: Then I don't see the problem; that is the result I get when I run this.

Comment: @ScottHunter - `"ccaxcc".strip("c")` would return `"ax"`, removing more than just the first and last letters

Comment: @Sayse: But OP said the posted code "deletes every single" of some character from the string, which it only does under certain circumstances (your example being one), and none that OP presented.

Answer (score 5):

Strip removes all instances of the letter from the start and end of a string until it encounters a character that isn't expected to be stripped, you can just slice

```
string[1:-1]
```

Otherwise you can use `removesuffix/prefix`

```
string.removesuffix(string[-1]).removeprefix(string[0])
```